# How to get VM series in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a VM (windows) in my azure.I tried seeing the tables in storage account but didn't get any help. I want to know the series of VM like A series,etc. Can i get this data from REST API also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You could use the following [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-get).

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vm}?api-version=2017-03-30
```

This is my test result in my lab.

[image]

Comment: OK. Now i am able to get the VM size name, but can i get the VM CPU data like CPU speed and manufacturer information(e.g Intel or what)?

Comment: @AbhayDwivedi Do you want to get CPU usage or just Azure VM CPU type? If you want to know CPU type, you could refer to this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stephw/2015/06/01/details-of-the-azure-processors-for-vm-sizes/).

Comment: Yeah i want exactly the same data but i was wondering if i could get this data through REST API?

Comment: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vm}/vmSizes?api-version=2017-03-30` This API could list cpu cores and memory, but it could not find CPU manufacturer. I check the API that Azure provides, it seems that it does not provides API to get CPU manufacturer.

Comment: @AbhayDwivedi Now, it is impossible to use API to get CPU manufacturer. Please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/16830625-api-for-providing-cpu-model-and-cpu-mhz-for-azure).